# symfony credentials issue with sfDoctrineGuard 5.x

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am using sfDoctrineGuard 5.x and I have configured my module credentials in security.yml like this:

```
all:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: [ admin ]
```

and my app/backend/config/security.yml:

```
default:
  is_secure: true
```

I have tested using:

`$this->getUser()->hasPermission('vendor')`: returned true
`$this->getUser()->hasPermission('admin')`: returned false

so I guess the users are inheriting credentials right. But still users with other credentials can access the module!

I have 3 types of group admin, client and vendor and similar permissions: admin, client and vendor!

And users having 'client' or 'vendor' credentials can access the module ignoring the credentials defined in the security.yml after login !

What could be the problem? Can anyone give me some direction?

oh, I am using sfForkedApplyPlugin for registration and profile editing process, which I don't think causing the issue, as I am testing with predefined fixture data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem just now!
It was the ***is_super_admin*** field in ***sf_guard_user*** table which was set to 1 for all my dummy users in fixture.yml :) ! 
That's why every users were getting access to all modules bypassing the credentials!